# C (not C++) pass by value/reference interview question

Tags: c, calling-convention

I've got a list of questions I like to ask to probe a candidates C skills for embedded systems programming. One of the standard questions I have, which is also on a lot of public question lists is this but I'm starting to think it's a bad question:

"Explain or contrast pass-by-value and pass-by-reference in C"

I tell the interviewee that the question has nothing to do with C++ references and I'm looking for an explanation of passing a pointer to a variable vs. a variable and how the callee can modify the variable referenced by the pointer. Extra points for explanation about how passing pointers to structs is more efficient.

Here's the question: is there really "pass by reference" in C?

The signature of the callee clearly defines what's being passed. It's not like you can pass either x or &x to a function and have the compiler figure out what to do. So I would argue that everything is C is pass by value and pass-by-reference is really just passing the value of a pointer.

Is there something fundamentally different about

```
void f(int *xarg);
...
int x;
int *xp = &x;
f(xp);
```

vs.

```
f(&x);
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Try to phrase the question in language-neutral terms: how would you go about implementing a function that received a X and did Y to it? What is the merit of the FlyWeight pattern and could you sketch an implementation in C?

Comment: @sehe "FlyWeight pattern" is language-neutral?? I consider myself fluent in C and I have never heard of it. I could answer the original interview question blindfolded and while I'm not currently looking for a job, I'd hate to be asked your language-neutral question for an interview for a C-related job.

Comment: I was showing creative thinking. Also, FlyWeight is a pattern. It _is_ language neutral (much like patterns like NullObject and Memento)

Comment: @sehe I do know what the Flyweight pattern is, and I don't see its relevance to this question. It's perfectly possible to be a good C or C++ programmer without having drunk (or at least not having quaffed) the Design Patterns KoolAid.

Comment: @Neil: True enough. I was just stretching the imagination a bit to show how you can ask for relevant understanding of parameter passing/value allocation efficiency and not mention 'pass by reference', or any language specific construct

Comment: A possible analogy - C does not have virtual functions, but you can put something together in C that implements all the functionality of virtual functions. So *you* have virtual functions in C, but C still doesn't have them. C also doesn't have pass-by-reference. But a pointer is a reference (in the general sense that it refers to something, not in the specific C++ sense). So, since you can pass a reference by value, you can get as close as needed to pass-by-reference for all practical purposes *except* the syntax looking right. And also except that you can't pass rvalues by pointer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no pass by reference in C.

The closest you can get is pass by pointer, which is actually a pass by value (except that it is the pointer that is copied, not the pointed-to object).

So, you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

No - there is no pass by reference in C - everything is pass by value. But I think it would be a bit hard on an interviewee if they explained pass by reference in terms of pointers and you rejected them because of that, unless you are looking for a language lawyer.

Comment: +1 this answer does the best job getting across that, while OP is right about C not having "pass by reference", it's a language-lawyer issue that probably does not belong in a job interview...

Comment: Right, I would give full points for any explanation that contrasts passing of pointer vs. variable, e.g. using the swap function, regardless of the exact wording. By the way, I like your and Etienne's answer equally but can't tell who was first, not that that really matters.

Comment: @Andrew I was first by about 30 seconds. Was almost a race at that point.

Answer (score 2):

C [does not have pass-by-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#Characteristics).

Why not refer to it as "pass-by-pointer" instead?

Comment: For an interview question that gives away too much of the answer. My goal in an interview for an embedded systems developer is to gauge how well they understand the details so I'm looking for them to come up with "pointer".

Answer (score 1):

C is always pass by value. There really isn't any difference between the code snippets you've posted. In fact an optimizing compiler would probably emit the same code either way.

Answer (score 1):

Of course C has "pass by reference"... it's a well established Comp. Sci. term that's widely used to refer to the practice of providing access to a variable from the calling context.  Crucially, it's the *pointed-to* variable that's passed by reference.  The pointer to it that is being passed by value is just the mechanism for this that's available in C.

Any good C programmer should know exactly what you mean by your original question and not get it confused with "references" as per C++ etc..

From the draft C99 Standard:

> A pointer type may be derived from a function type, an object type, or an incomplete
>   type, called the **referenced** type. A pointer type describes an object **whose value
>   provides a reference** to an entity of **the referenced type**. A pointer type derived from
>   the referenced type T is sometimes called ‘‘pointer to T’’. The construction of a
>   pointer type from a referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’.

(That said, your insight that pointers are passed as values is an important part of understanding the hands-on way the language works, and valuable in its own right.)

(Meta-discussion - I rather think there's been one well-respected S.O. contributor take an extreme view on this and others are jumping on the bandwagon... the conformity in current "C lacks pass-by-reference" answers is definitely not representative of industry-accepted terminology.  Not pointing fingers there - I haven't even tried to find out who responded first.  As in judging art for competitions, published critiques etc. - you can't do it fairly and responsibly unless you form your own opinion before considering others.  That said, another plausible explanation is that the logic in the question itself softened everyone up :-) )

Comment: Tony, thanks for the prose, nicely said. I largely agree that pass-by-reference is a well-established term and good C programmers would understand what is meant. However, my recent interview experience for embedded systems developers is indicating that this particular question is not a good one. I think it may be better to ask the candidate to implement a swap function and make sure they know basic pointer syntax and semantics.

Comment: @Andrew: interesting - I certainly can't see any down sides to asking for tangible proof of understanding of these concepts... that's definitely the bottom line.  Cheers.